# WooCommerce - different attributes for each category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a question about WooCommerce.

For example let's say that store will have 5 categories (Phones, Laptop, PC, Keyboard, Mouse). And each category product will have different attributes.
Phones will have screen size, OS, processor. Keyboard will have connection type and such.

How can I display those attributes for each category? Layered Nav widget shows only one attribute. Is there a widget which will show all attributes for each category?

Comment: Where you want to show the attributes? in shop page sidebar or in product single page?

Comment: I want to show attributes on product category page. Each category will have different attributes, depending on products. Is there a plugin that could do that?

Comment: try this plugin [YITH WooCommerce Ajax Product Filter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-ajax-navigation/).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I managed to solve it using the plugin *WC Ajax Product Filter*.
Go to *Appeareance* > *Widgets*. Then add the WC Ajax widgets to *WooCommerce Sidebar*.